# Installed new version of python, Now I can't use the libraries I've installed for the older version in Mac

Tags: python, python-2.7, mysql-python

I am using an older version of **Python 2.7.3**, but I realize that it is a 32 bit version and I needed a **64 bit** version to be able to use `MySQLdb`.

Also, I have other libraries that I have downloaded for Python 2.7.3. Now my problem is, none of those libraries can be imported to my newly installed version of **Python 2.7.5**. Just wondering if there is a way for both versions to share libraries.

When I tried installing again `MySQLdb`, it wouldn't let me because it's already installed, but under Python 2.7.3. Any solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Just wondering if there is a way were both version can share libraries.

While it is possible share pure-Python modules between two different installations of Python, at least if they have the same minor version, you generally cannot share C extension modules like `MySQLdb`. And you *definitely* cannot use a 32-bit build of a module with a 64-bit Python.

---

> And When I tried installing again MySQLdb, it won't let me because it's already installed, but under 2.7.3.

There are two possible problems here.

First, you may just be using the wrong Python to do the installation. If you use the 32-bit Python 2.7.3 to run `python setup.py install`, or the `easy_install` or `pip` from that copy of Python, it will install into your 2.7.3 site-packages. This one is easy to fix—just use the 64-bit Python 2.7.5, or its `easy_install` or `pip`.

More seriously, you may have both installations pointing at the same site-packages directory and interfering with each other. This one is pretty much impossible to fix; you're not going to make it work.

---

More generally, it's difficult to have two Python installations with the same X.Y minor version on the same machine, and you really shouldn't try to do it unless you have a very good reason to do so. A much better idea is to completely uninstall both Pythons, including their site-packages, then do a clean install of 2.7.5, then reinstall all of your libraries.

(Also, note that if you're using OS X 10.7 or higher, you already have a 64-bit Python 2.7.2 pre-installed by Apple, and you can't get rid of it, and it can also cause similar problems for you.)